# Hissing a word or phrase?

Tags: verbs

What do novelists mean when they say someone hissed something? Not made a hissing sound, but just hissed some words. I have never heard anyone do this. it is used all the time. befuddled.

Answer (score 3):

It means that person spoke harshly in a whisper or half-whisper. The expression carries overtones of anger or disapproval.

Comment: Thanks so much. That has always been my best guess, but it seems an ill usage; a half whisper is hardly a hiss. Perhaps a hoarse rasp, but true hissing is something else, I feel. The snakes union will take umbrage. But o well . . .

Comment: @DavidAvshalomov A whisper removes all voicing from the utterance, so the most prominent elements will be voiceless continuants--in English, /s/ and /f/, which are pretty hissy.

Answer (score 1):

"Hiss" is the sound commonly attributed to a snake.

When I read that someone hissed some words, I imagine their delivery to have a snake-like quality; threatening, venomous, evil or short tempered.

Fortunately, like you, I rarely come across situations in real life where people "hiss", but it is very common in cinema and drama.